# Update: Override method from custom control on user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

good morning.

this is something that I'd like to achieve.

for `CustomControlA`, I have

```
public void OverrideableMethod()
{
// some codes here
}
```

and I have `UserControlB`. 
I would like to "override" the method from `CustomControlA` on `UserControlB`. **is this possible? if it is, how to?**

the best thing I can come up is to create a method of the same name on `UserControlB` and invoke `CustomControlA.OverrideableMethod()` from there.

---

**Update:**
*Thanks for the answers, I appreciate them.*

the code is something like this:

```
public class CustomControlA : CustomControl
{
    public virtual void OverrideableMethod()
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public class UserContorlB : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected CustomControlA someVariableForCustomControlA;

    // here lies the problem, on how to override CustomControlA.OverrideableMethod() here
    // without inheriting CustomControlA itself
}
```

here lies to problem. as much as possible, I'd want to keep away from inheriting CustomControlA, for reasons allowing `UserControlB` to inherit one more base class. 
**is this possible to override `CustomControlA.OverrideableMethod()` given the scenario above?**

Comment: why are you doing it this way?

Comment: and no you cannot override CustomControlA this way, you could however add an Event to CustomControlA and then register to it from USerControlB

Comment: @TMcKeown I was hoping to get the UserControlB to inherit another base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use virtual and override keywords to override the methods in the child class if at all UserControlB is a child class of CustomControlA. If not then its not method overriding.

```
public class CustomControlA
{
     public virtual void OverrideableMethod()
     {
      // some codes here
      }
}

public class UserControlB: CustomControlA
{
     public override void OverrideableMethod()
     {
         // some codes here
     }

}
```

UPDATE (based on the updated part of your question):
No its not possible to do the overriding(actually you are not even trying to do overriding) but you can do something like below. You should always call `UserContorlB.OverrideableMethod()` but make sure you have some condition based on which the proper method will be called.

```
public class CustomControlA
{
    public void OverrideableMethod()
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public class UserContorlB : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected CustomControlA someVariableForCustomControlA;

    public void OverrideableMethod()
    {
        if(some condition is true)
        {
             someVariableForCustomControlA.OverrideableMethod();
        }
        else 
        {
             // do some logic here
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure CustomControlA is public otherwise it isn't able to be inherited.

Comment: thanks. your answer was one of the paths am thinking of taking. I have updated the question. can you take a look at it?

Comment: Nope. Its not possible. How are you planning to call the methods in both classes?

Comment: @AdarshShah that is the question, if it is possible. :)

Comment: Then no is the answer.

Comment: @AdarshShah thanks for that, I realized it right from the start, but needed to ask for more heads to fill in the blanks, so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

You should post your code for the controls to make this clear.

It is possible under the following conditions, and btw you wouldn't be invoking CustomControlA.OverrideableMethod() from UserControlB.  If UserControlB inherited CustomControlA then the method exists in UserControlB:

```
public class CustomControlA : UserControl
{

    public virtual void OverrideableMethod() {  /* code the default implementation */ }
}
```

Your UserControlB would extend/inherit CustomControlA

```
public class UserControlB : CustomControlA
{

    public override void OverrideableMethod() {  /* implement whatever you want */ }
}
```

If CustomControlA's method had code you wanted to execute as well as NEW code in UserControlB you would do this:

```
public class UserControlB : CustomControlA
{

    public override void OverrideableMethod() 
    {
         base.OverrideableMethod();
         /*
            additional code here
         */  
    }
}
```

The best practice for inherited methods when building base classes that will fire descendant code is as follows:

```
public class CustomControlA : UserControl
{

    public void OverrideableMethod() 
    {
       //You can code here for things before the overrideable method
       OnOverrideableMethod();
       //You can code here for things after the overrideable method
    }

    protected virtual void OnOverrideableMethod() { }
}


public class UserControlB : CustomControlA
{

    protected override void OnOverrideableMethod() 
    {
       /*  implement here */
    }
}
```

This prevents any direct calls to the "OnXXXX" methods and forces calls to the public/well defined methods.  It provides you the ability to add code before and/or after the "OnXXX" method.

Comment: thanks. your answer was one of the paths am thinking of taking. I have updated the question. can you take a look at it?